# Why php doesn't exit from loop via break?

Tags: php

I have the `for` loop:

I have an `$request->photos` array. Keys from this array are:

```
[1,3,5,8]
```

In the end, I need to get an array, where indexes are from 1 to 8 and items are boolean variables. Aside from this, I need to save the photos from the array.

Then I need to loop through the array and check if `$i` equals to `$key`:

```
foreach($request->photos as $key => $photo) {
    for($i = 1; $i < 9; $i++) {
        if ($key == $i) {
            dump($key);
            $path = storage_path('app/public/images/' . $pdf->id . '-' . $key . '.png');
            $image = Image::make($photo->getRealPath())->widen(300)->save($path);
            $imagesArray[$i] = true;
            break;
        } else {
            $imagesArray[$i] = false;
        }                    
    }
}
```

And if `$key` equals to `$i`, I need to exit from loop. But in this case, `break` doesn't work and `for` loop goes on even if `$key` was found.

Why it goes like that?

Comment: your logic is wrong `$imagesArray[$i] = array_fill(0,10, false);
foreach($request->photos as $key => $photo) {
   $path = storage_path('app/public/images/' . $pdf->id . '-' . $key . '.png');
   $image = Image::make($photo->getRealPath())->widen(300)->save($path);
   $imagesArray[$i] = true;
}`

Comment: @PatrickQ in this case, `$key` goes from 1. It goes from the frontend through `<input name="photos[1]">`.

Comment: @splash58 send it as an answer, it's quite difficult to read

Comment: You're going to need to provide more code/context.  Sample input, desired output/behavior, current output/behavior.  Are you wanting the first to loop once, the second to loop twice, etc?

Comment: What makes you think the `for` loop isn't breaking? You start it again for the next element of `$request->photos`, maybe whatever you're seeing is coming from the next iteration of the `foreach` loop.

Comment: I agree with @splash58, at least in that it looks like the for loop isn't really necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop is unnecessary. Just use the keys of `$request->photos` as the keys to fill in `$imagesArray`.

```
$imagesArray = array_fill(1, 8, false);
foreach ($request->photos as $key => $photo) {
    dump($key);
    $path = storage_path('app/public/images/' . $pdf->id . '-' . $key . '.png');
    $image = Image::make($photo->getRealPath())->widen(300)->save($path);
    $imagesArray[$key] = true;
}
```